# Error while installing eclipse(eclipse-jee-helios-linux-gtk-x86_64) in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I downloaded and extracted the eclipse 64 bit version for my ubuntu system.The download and the extraction was successful however I get the below error when I try running eclipse

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/ubuntu/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/ubuntu/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/ubuntu/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.0.v20100503/eclipse_1307.so
-startup /home/ubuntu/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-exitdata 230012
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/ubuntu/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
```

Please do help me out.

My eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this link http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-the-latest-eclipse-in-ubuntu-16-04-15-10/. to install eclispe. you said you are lunching the eclipse.exe and I think normaly files with.exe extension does not belong to ubuntu

Comment: I am sorry.I am meant eclipse and not eclipse.exe.

Comment: are you sure java is well installed? tried this "java -version" in oder to see whether it is or not the case?

Comment: openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)                                                                                                         It's installed well.